# Django ForeinKey in template

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm building a multivendor in django. I have a general Merchant table and products table. How can i use the merchant shop name in product template.

models.py

```
class Merchant(models.Model):
    shop_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    shop_address=models.CharField(max_length=100)
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    merchant=models.ManyToManyField(Merchant)
```

details.html

{{product.name}}

{{product.brand}}

{{product.category__shop_name}}

the shop_name is not appearing in the template.
thanks beforhand.

Comment: Because of the `ManyToManyField`, there can be zero, one or *more* `Merchant`s, so `{{ product.whatever.shop_name }}`, makes no sense, since this is not a single item.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem what do you suggest  i do now.

Answer (score 0):

Use loops

```
{% for merchant in product.merchant.all %}
    {{ merchant.shop_name }}
{% endfor %}
```